# Decorator Design pattern issue

Tags: design-patterns

I'm struggling about the correctness of using decorator pattern.
Let's take an example from Diablo 2 game. There are items (e.g) swords, that you can decorate with jewels and the swords become changed e.g more attack points or swords name modification. So in this point of view the sword is an concrete object that would be decorated and the jewels are decorators. But jewels could also stay as independent , standalone items and they also have name, description and other specifiers. How to resolve this problem ? I would to have an 'jewel' that is independent, and can get his name, description but I would also be able to decorate some sword with this jevel. Notice that both, the jevel and the sword have common specifiers like name or description that are independent. While decorating a sword with jevel, the sword have to become a new name e.g "sword with amethyst, while getting the name of independent amethyst it should return "an old amethyst". Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Jewels should not be decorators as they don't represent the same functionality, i.e. sword. However, you could have `SwordWithJewels`, or in pseudo code:

```
interface ISword { Stab(); }
class Sword : ISword { Stab();  }
class SwordWithJewels : ISword { Stab(); }
```

`SwordWithJewels` should probably take jewels as an argument during construction, directly or indirectly via another object that owns them, and use that information to calculate hit strength or name or whatever you need.

But note that this is just an option, and might be overkill depending on context. If you consider jewels an inventory item, then it might make more sense to use some other approach (I deliberately avoid the word pattern as starting with the idea "i need to use some pattern for this" often results in bad code). Just traversing the list of inventory items and letting each of them add or remove strength points from the hit could also make sense, which is more similar to visitor (if you want a familiar name).

Comment: Can `Sword` compose the jewels in this context?

Comment: Hmmm idea about constructing a new Instance SwordWithJewels while having original Sword is a bad idea, beceause the sword should always be te same,original instance. If I would to put a jewel there, I would not to create a new sword and copy all other sword properties from 'Sword' to 'SwordWithJewels'. I think it disturbs the Object oriented programming concept, don't you think ? A sword should always be the same Sword instance, with or without jewels. Secondly, when creating a new SwordWithJewels instance, the program handles 2 different sword instances,while in the game should exist only one

Comment: Wrong. That is the point of decorator pattern: to have one object wrapping another and exposing the same interface with augmented functionality. That's also the reason i implied that the decorator is a poor choice here. Don't pick patterns in order to be compliant with literature. Use them when they make sense.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your answer, could you repeat it more detailed ? In my previos post I was talking about your solution with 'Sword' and 'SwordWithJewels' and not about decorator pattern, so I don't see any connection beetwen my previous post and your last answer.

Comment: You mentioned having two objects etc - the decorator is about wrapping the objects, so you will have multiple instances forwarding calls between them. Although you don't mention it in the last comment, your question is titled 'decorator ...'. The connection is that you can't consider multiple objects bad idea, while still being on decorator topic. That being said, there are no problems with multiple objects - they are only visible at the moment of construction, afterwards the client deals with only one object.